# Get all relations name in laravel5 model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have model include of several relation for example like this:

```
public function NewsCategory()
{ 
   return $this->belongsTo("News\Model\NewsCategory");
}
public function NewsImage()
{ 
   return $this->belongsTo("News\Model\NewsImage");
}
public function NewsTag()
{ 
   return $this->belongsTo("News\Model\NewsTag");
}
```

and relations create dynamically.
How can I get all this class name?
In this example I want
 `NewsCategory,NewsImage,NewsTag`

Comment: Check this [method](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/blob/master/src/Console/ModelsCommand.php#L306).

Comment: How can I use this?

Comment: you can use this Model:with('NewsCategory','NewsImage','NewsTag')->get();

Comment: I know. But I want get `'NewsCategory','NewsImage','NewsTag'` name.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_relationsToArray

Comment: thanks but return null array

Answer (score 3):

one approach is to as follows :

```
$results = ModelClass::where(x,y)->with(['NewsCategory','NewsImage','NewsTag'])->first();
```

then you can use getRelations();

```
$relationshipKeys = array_keys($results->getRelations());
```

Answer (score 3):

```php
$model_specific_method_name_array = 
    array_diff(
        get_class_methods(<YourModel>), 
        get_class_methods(<AnotherDummyEloquentModelWithoutAnyMethods>)
    );
```

Then remove other known methods on your model from array.