# How can I get the relation's name which is defined between two models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Assume I have two models `Company` and `Employee` in Laravel 6. I defined a `belongsTo` and `hasMany` relations between `Company` and `Employee` already.

Now the question is: Is there any method that I detect or determine the existing relation's name between these two models in the run time?

For example inside the code I access to an instance of model `Company`. Then I want to know what is the relation's name between `$company` and model `Employee`.

For clarification in the run time I don't know the type of the relation between models and I want to know is there any relation defined between these two? And if yes what is the name of that relation? Is it `employee` or `employees`? Is it `company` or `companies`?

Comment: i don't think that it is possible to do that it depends on how you built your model and migration

Comment: Exactly this is what I am looking for to know. But I have not yet reached to a clear answer for.

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37896955/get-all-relations-name-in-laravel5-model) it may help

Comment: this [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/get-all-model-relationships) is awesome from laracasts

Comment: Yes this was the answer. But complicated method that has a lot of overhead. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Me to it make me confused but i think that is the only way to make this for this time